# C# what is the best way to parallelize Form Instances?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parallel-processing, task

I have a main class that creates `FormAccount` instances with a custom constructor that execute some initialization methods that are time consuming and I need to parallelize it.

What is the proper and efficient way to parallelize it? I am using parallel task as follows but is not working as desired.

```
Parallel.For(0, numAccounts, i =>
{
    //create form instances
    FormAccount formAccount = new FormAccount(listAccountsParams[i]);
    listAccountsForms.Add(formAccount);

    //show all forms
    listAccountsForms[listAccountsForms.Count() - 1].Show();
});
```

Comment: What is the type of the application? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: "not working as desired" could you explain the desired behaviour and exactly how it's "not working"

Comment: If possible, isolate the time consuming code and run that in parallel, without any UI stuff. Also `listAccountsForms[listAccountsForms.Count() - 1]` might not return the form just added in the same thread.

Comment: Is WinForms. @C.Evenhuis, thanks I isolate the heavy code without UI and see a big improvement. However, now I have the problem that the UI controls are mixed. I am creating a new thread so there is a different issue... Thanks for your support

Comment: You shouldn't do long operation tasks on the UI thread. Also, don't create windows/controls on a non-UI thread. So it means that if you want to do some long operation tasks, handle it within the Form. (create a `Task DoCalculation(...)` in combination with `Task.WhenAll(form1CalculationTask. form2CalculationTask. form3CalculationTask);`  for example

Comment: A second question is, why is the calculation part of the form/constructor?